# kde keyboard problems Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shortcut-keys, kde

I have Unity & Gnome 3.4 installed successfully.  All Dell keyboard keys work perfectly with both.  I installed kde - full via terminal.  Everything is working great except for the hotkeys.  No calculator, no Mute, nothing.  I check which keyboard is selected and choose Dell Multimedia USB Keyboard.  No luck.

How do I get my Dell keyboard to work with kde - the same keyboard that works with Unity & Gnome 3.4.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different menus for changing keyboard shortcut settings in KDE. You can find them by searching for "shortcut" in the *Kickoff* menu.

[image: "shortcut" search in Kickoff menu]

For example, to change the hotkey for the Mute action, you go to *Global Keyboard Shortcuts* and select *KMix* (which responds for sound).

[image: Global Keyboard Shortcuts – KDE Control Module]

To add your own shortcuts, you can go to *Custom Shortcuts*. Let's make a shortcut for *KCalc* – KDE's default calculator. Right-click on the box to the left, select *New* → *Global Shortcut* → *Command/URL*. Give your new shortcut some name, go to *Trigger* tab, pick a key, then go to *Action* tab and write `kcalc` there. You can launch different applications, open web pages or perform other command line actions, that depends on what you write here.

[image: Custom Shortcuts – KDE Control Module]

Also note that there are per-application shortcut settings in each application's *Settings* → *Configure Shortcuts...* menu.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I will give it a try later when I have more time.  I find it a bit odd that a Dell Multimedia USB keyboard isn't configured.  I can see how many people would not want to be bothered with KDE for that reason.  I do like it as it appears to be fast and a nice change from Unity and Gnome 3.4.

Comment: @chazdg Going through all the *System Settings* can be very rewarding.

Comment: @chazdg And instead of *thanks* this site has upvotes.

Comment: I got you covered.  Well,I got the Mute Button working.  I have tried every configuration for a basic calculator, but it simply will not work.  I tried everything from your example to going with System Settings.  I can get any calculator I want by right clicking the desktop and typing it in.  Then, I tried to assign it the correct key, but it still won't work.  The other key I can't find is the Launch key.  I'm not sure how rewarding it is to go over the entire thing, entry by enty.  Any help you can give is appreciated.

Comment: @chazdg You probably haven't installed KDE's calculator. Try `gcalctool` or whatever the GNOME's calculator is called instead of `kcalc`. Not sure what you mean by "launch key" though. There is no good way to assign a shortcut to Super key. Try Alt+F2 (this can be changed under *Global Keyboard Shortcuts* → *Run Command Interface*) or Alt+F1. P.S. I said looking through all the settings is rewarding because you will find many, many ways to make the system better for yourself, not just hotkeys.

Comment: "Launch key" meaning the 'calculator button' on my Dell USB Keyboard. By the way, gcaltool is installed - just checked with Synaptic.  Alt+F2 works great.  Assigning the appropriate "calculator" button on my keyboard does not seem to work.

Comment: No I would not like to automatically move this discussion to chat.  I have never found that option viable...I find the rules of this website silly and not terribly relevant.  I have gotten much important information mixed in with the rules that the powers that be impose irrelevant.  Chat is a waste of time.